# `Own a politician` means `bribe a politician`?

Tags: word-meaning

In the reddit: [own somebody](https://www.reddit.com/r/southafrica/comments/5n5jrc/do_white_people_enjoy_living_in_south_africa/)

> Avoid tax? Rip off consumers? Own a politician? This is heaven man.

"Own a politician" means "bribe a politician"?

Comment: To be able to control a politician, perhaps from prior bribes or contributions, perhaps from knowing a fact that could end the politician's career if divulged.  (That's what it could mean in general; I'm not interpreting anything at that link)

Comment: I'd say you bribe him to the point where he cannot refuse you - then you 'own' him. So owning is the intention of bribing.

Comment: I've no special knowledge of the murky world of political intrigue, but it seems to me quite possible that more "owned" (shouldn't that be "pwned" today? :) politicians are probably in that state because of ***blackmail*** (catastrophically damaging info will be revealed if they don't toe the line) rather than ***bribery*** (attractive bungs are available if they *do* what the bad guys want).

Comment: THis definition probably helps. http://www.dictionary.com/browse/own-someone  ... in particular, the **dominate**. As FumbleFingers says, you would be more likely to dominate a politician by blackmail than by bribery- or by combining the two. Bribe the politician once, and thereafter you can threaten to reveal that the politician accepted a bribe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The full comment is describing the benefits of living in South Africa:

> There are also benefits to having a disfunctional government, like getting to do whatever you want. Feel like speeding at 220 kph? Bribe the cop? No problem. Overtake on the shoulder of the road? Easy peasy. Avoid tax? Rip off consumers? Own a politician? This is heaven man.

The key to understanding the phrase is the context.  The author is describing the benefits of a dysfunctional government.  He goes on to describe many levels of corruption, such as bribing police to let you speed and drive unsafely.

In this context, we are talking about "owning a politician", which implies a deeper level of corruption than a simple bribe.  For example, the author describes speeding, and bribing a cop to ignore it.  This is a simple business transaction - the author buys the cop's co-operation, but we wouldn't say that they "own" the cop.  If they speed again, the cop will expect another bribe.

To "own" someone in the context of corruption means to have someone under your control.  This is more than just a single favor - it is unthinkable that someone you "own" would not do whatever you ask.  In a drama, this might include threats of violence or blackmail, but in the real world a sizable donation is typically enough.  If you routinely provide the funds necessary for a politician to get re-elected, then they owe you their job.  Under those circumstances, we would expect them to cheerfully use their power to help their friends.

One further note:  To "own" someone is an insulting way to describe this relationship, particularly in a country with a history like South Africa.  Telling someone "I own you" is very hostile. (e.g. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JAbGGIV45Ng ) The only place we would expect someone to use this term to describe a relationship is if they wanted to deliberately insult the politician involved.

Comment: Insult, or more likely, *threaten*.